# Wordpress Custom Post Type conflict with sub page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, conflict, taxonomy

Heres the setup:
• Page called Weddings with children pages called winter, spring, fall, summer.
• Custom post type called 'weddings'.
• Taxonomy called wedding_type assigned to the custom post type weddings.

When I go to the page website.com/weddings, it shows you all of the weddings posts, all types on one page. When I go to website.com/weddings/summer, I want to use a different template so I can query the wedding posts, with the taxomomy 'wedding_type' of summer. But I get a 404. I believe this is because it is looking for a wedding post called 'summer'.

Any Ideas? I don't really have any code to post, I set this up via the CPT UI plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Change the slug of your parent page "Weddings". Currently the slug of that page may be "weddings", you can change it to like "all-weddings" or "list-weddings".

Your problem will automatically get resolve as soon as you change the slug of your page named "weddings".

Answer (score 1):

There's a conflict of URLs here. It's going to look for a post_name of summer with a post_type of weddings.

Your best option is to remove the custom post type and apply your custom taxonomy to the pages post type. You can also create templates and choose the one you want to use on a page-by-page basis. Essentially everything will be a child of the weddings hierarchy.

Another option is to change the name of the root page hierarchy or the name of the post type (wedding, seasons...)